# Visual Studio Code & PHP: Escaping Quotes in Echo Statements

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

All, I have started using Visual Studio Code for managing a large PHP project (switched away from PHPEdit), and it is working great!  However, there is one annoyance I have and I can't seem to find an extension that fixes it.  When typing an echo statement such as `echo("<div class=\"newDiv\">");`, I've noticed that VSCode does not automatically realize you are in a string and escape your quotes automatically.  This was a feature that saved a TON of time in my past IDE.  Now, if I am typing fast and not thinking, I end up with the following assuming it was going to escape quotes, when it doesn't: `echo("<div class="newDiv">");`, which is obviously not valid PHP.

What am I missing here?  Is there a way for quotes to be escaped when inside a string automatically?  Perhaps an extension that I am not aware of?

Comment: Type `echo( '<div class="newDiv">'  );` ?

Comment: A very good idea is to use single quotes whenever possible. For HTML attributes you use double and if you have to use them in another combination you have to do so consciously. Also `echo` is not a function but a language construct, so you are not required to use parentheses with it, which makes things clearer and less confusing.

Comment: Does this happen throughout every string or just the `echo` construct when passing in a string? Also, my VSC does not have this error with PHP, so I have a suspicion that something wonky is up with your application settings.

Comment: How would VS code know when you are inside of a string and in need of auto-escaping and when not?

Comment: How is it supposed to know that when you type the second `"` that you mean it to be an interior quote, which should be escaped, rather than the end of the string?

Comment: What was your previous IDE? I use PhpStorm, it doesn't auto-escape quotes, either.

Answer (score 0):

There's an extension called [Escape-quotes](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=milovidov.escape-quotes). Install the extension, then highlight the block of code you want to escape and right-click. A new option "Escape Quotes" and "Unescape Quotes" will now be available.